# Running Ubuntu in UTM Vm on M2 chip Macbook - Not promtet with "Install Ubuntu" or "Try Ubuntu"

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, macbook, m2

I am trying to run Ubuntu as a VM using UTM. I have successfully set everything up, however, when I should be promtet with "Install Ubuntu" or "Try Ubuntu" I get this:

[image]

Anyone know what I should do to get this to run properly?

I have a M2 chip Macbook Pro and downloaded the LTS version of Ubuntu 22.04.3.

I have tried rearranging the booting order in all possible ways.

In advance; Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct image for your PC? Seeing that you are using the Macbook Pro with M2 chip you need to download the arm64 version of the 22.04.3 distro. So: I recommend you checking what you downloaded, and use the **22.04.3-arm64** version.

[Here is also a nice article](https://techblog.shippio.io/how-to-run-an-ubuntu-22-04-vm-on-m1-m2-apple-silicon-9554adf4fda1) describing the process using a Macbook with M1 chip (which has the same architecture (ARM) as you do on your M2), so it will be the same, just that the article uses the 22.04-arm64.

Comment: Spot on @Mari T-J !! I realise I had the amd image to begin with. It is all running properly now. The article literally answered all my questions.

Comment: Good to know, @Rory!!